# SwiftUI: Animating border width animates also the height

Tags: ios, swift, animation, swiftui

I am trying to create a "glowing" animation to certain view in my app but the animation behaves a bit weird. The correct animation can be seen to the time widget and the wrong behaviour to the exercise widget.

[image]

You can find the code bellow:

```
    struct InformationPanel:View {
    
    @Environment(\.fontSize) private var fontSize
    @State var isAnimating = false
    let glows:Bool
    let title:String
    let value:String?
    let icon:String
    
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color(Asset.Colors.semiTransparentBackground.color)
                .opacity(0.43)
                .cornerRadius(20)
                .overlay(
                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20, style: .circular)
                        .stroke(Color.white, lineWidth: glows && isAnimating ? 4 : 0)
                        .animation(.linear(duration: 1).repeatForever(),value: isAnimating)
                        .scaleEffect(1)
                
                        .opacity(0.65)
                        .onAppear {
                            isAnimating = true
                        }
                        
                )
                
                
            VStack(alignment: .leading,spacing: 8) {
                HStack(spacing:8) {
                    CircularImage(image: icon)
                    
                    
                    Text(title)
                        .font(.system(size: 20, weight: .bold))
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity,alignment: .leading)
                        .foregroundColor(.black)
                }
                .padding(.top,2)
                .padding(.leading,6)
                
                
                Text(value ?? " ")
                    .font(.system(size: fontSize ?? 30, weight: .bold))
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity,maxHeight: .infinity,alignment: .center)
                    .foregroundColor(.black)
                    .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                    .lineLimit(3)
                    .minimumScaleFactor(0.5)
            }
            .padding(.vertical,4)
            .animation(nil,value: isAnimating)   
        }   
    }   
}




struct WorkoutView:View {
    
    @StateObject private var viewModel:WorkoutViewModel
    
    @State private var exercisingState:WorkoutState = .startingUp
    @State private var timeRemaining:Int? = nil
    @State private var duration:TimeInterval = 0
    @State private var isPaused:Bool = false
    @State private var exersice:String? = nil
    @State private var nextExersice:String? = nil
    @State private var round = 0
    
    
    private let timer = Timer.TimerPublisher(interval: 1,tolerance: 0.1, runLoop: .main, mode: .common).autoconnect()
    
    
    init(routine:Routine) {
        self.init(viewModel: WorkoutViewModel(routine: routine))
    }
    
    init(viewModel:WorkoutViewModel) {
        _viewModel = StateObject(wrappedValue: viewModel)
    }
    
    @ViewBuilder
    private func backgroundView() -> some View {
        switch exercisingState {
        case .startingUp, .roundReset:
            Color.yellow
        case .rest:
            Color.red
        case .work:
            Color.green
        }
    }
    
    private func control(image:String,action:() -> Void) -> some View {
        
        Button(action: {
            self.isPaused.toggle()
        }) {
            Image(image)
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                .frame(width: 20)
            
        }
        .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
        .background(.white)
        .clipShape(Circle())
    }
    
    
    
    private func titleBarView() -> some View {
        HStack(spacing:16) {
            
            control(image: isPaused ? "play" : "pause",action: {
                isPaused.toggle()
                
            })
            
            
            Spacer()
            
            Text(exercisingState.title)
                .lineLimit(1)
                .font(.system(size: 24, weight: .bold))
                .foregroundColor(.black)
            
            Spacer()
            
            control(image: "stop",action: {
                isPaused.toggle()
                
            })
            
            
            
            
        }
    }
    
    
    private func countdownBar() -> some View{
        
        AnimationView(duration: duration ,paused: $isPaused) { progress in
            
            CountDownProgressView(progress: progress)
                .frame(width: 30)
        }
        .id(duration)
        .id(exercisingState)
    }
    
    
    
    private func timeWidget() -> some View {
        InformationPanel(
            glows: true,
            title: Strings.time,
            value: timeRemaining?.description,
            icon:  Asset.Images.timeWidget.name
        )
            .fontSize(85)
    }
    
    private func roundWidget() -> some View {
        InformationPanel(
            glows: false, title: Strings.round,
            value: round.description,
            icon: Asset.Images.roundWidget.name
        )
            .fontSize(45)
    }
    
    private func exerciseWidget() -> some View {
        InformationPanel(
            glows: true,
            title:Strings.exercise,
            value: exersice,
            icon: Asset.Images.exerciseWidget.name
        )
            .fontSize(25)
    }
    
    private func nextExerciseWidget() -> some View {
        InformationPanel(
            glows: false,
            title: Strings.next,
            value: nextExersice,
            icon: Asset.Images.nextWidget.name
        )
            .fontSize(25)
        
    }
    
    
    private func main() -> some View {
        VStack(spacing:16) {
            
            titleBarView()
            
            HStack(spacing:16) {
                GeometryReader { reader in
                    VStack(spacing:16) {
                        
                        timeWidget()
                            .frame(height:150)
                        
                        roundWidget()
                            .frame(height:100)
                        
                        exerciseWidget()
                        nextExerciseWidget()
                    }
                    
                }
                countdownBar()
            }
            
        }
        
        .padding(.horizontal,16)
        
        
    }
    
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            
            self.backgroundView()
                .transition(.opacity.animation(.linear(duration: 0.24)))
                .ignoresSafeArea()
            
            main()
                .padding(.vertical,8)
            
        }
        .navigationBarHidden(true)
        .onAppear(perform: viewModel.start)
        .model(viewModel: viewModel)
        .onReceive(viewModel.$currentPhase) { currentPhase in
            guard let currentPhase = currentPhase else { return }
            exercisingState = currentPhase.state
            duration = currentPhase.durationTimeInterval
            timeRemaining = currentPhase.duration
            exersice = currentPhase.state.excercise?.name
            nextExersice = currentPhase.state.nextExcercise?.name
            round = currentPhase.round
        }
        .onReceive(timer) { tick in
            guard !viewModel.isFinished else { return }
            guard !isPaused else { return }
            guard let timeRemaining = timeRemaining else { return }
            if timeRemaining <= 1 {
                viewModel.next()
            }
            self.timeRemaining = timeRemaining - 1
            
        }
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears each of the `RoundedRectangles` is doing the same thing, which would make sense as you are using `.stroke()` on them. When you change the `.stroke()` width on a built in shape like this, one half of that border is added on to the size of the shape. However, changing that to `.strokeBorder()` will keep in inside the bounds of the shape. [Paul Hudson has a good explanation](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/books/ios-swiftui/adding-strokeborder-support-with-insettableshape). You can see it very clearly in the following code:

```
struct GlowingRect: View {
    @State var isAnimating: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Color.blue
                .opacity(0.43)
                .cornerRadius(20)
                .frame(width: 300, height: 100)
                .overlay(
                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20, style: .circular)
                        .strokeBorder(Color.orange, lineWidth: isAnimating ? 20:0)
                        .animation(.linear(duration: 2).repeatForever(), value: isAnimating)
                        .scaleEffect(1)
                    
                        .opacity(0.65)
                        .onAppear {
                            isAnimating = true
                        }
                )
            Color.green
                .opacity(0.43)
                .cornerRadius(20)
                .frame(width: 300, height: 100)
                .overlay(
                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20, style: .circular)
                        .stroke(Color.orange, lineWidth: isAnimating ? 20:0)
                        .animation(.linear(duration: 2).repeatForever(), value: isAnimating)
                        .scaleEffect(1)
                    
                        .opacity(0.65)
                        .onAppear {
                            isAnimating = true
                        }
                )
        }
    }
}
```